# Why does sin(theta) turn into -sin(theta) here?

Tags: trigonometry

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g76Vy.png)

When multiplying both sides by a common denominator, I noticed the sin(theta) of the right side starts out positive; After being multiplied with another sin(theta), which is also positive, it somehow becomes negative.

Does the fact that the fraction it is a part of is being subtracted have anything to do with it?

if the whole equation was exactly the same but it was negative sin(theta), would that make it positive? as in sin(theta)cos(theta) +sin^2(theta)?

Comment: 1) use mathjax 2) re-write the question with equations

Comment: Question 1) $-(a+b)=-a-b$ and question 2)  $-(a-b)=-a+b$

Comment: the negative is distributed lol

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign out front still has to be distributed through.  In symbols to potentially clarify the algebraic situation,
$$
-(a+b)c = -ac -bc.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a subtraction symbol in front of the fraction, as marked with an arrow in the image below:

[image]